# Gevent Pool apply_async

Tags: python, python-3.x, gevent

How do you prevent your program for stopping with `pool.apply_async` in gevent
what I mean is

```
import gevent
from gevent.monkey import patch_all
from gevent.pool import Pool

pool = Pool(10)

def print_num(num):
    print(num)


numbers  = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for number in numbers:
   self.pool.apply_async(print_num, args=(number,))
```

now if we ran the code above as is the program will close and the workers havent finished everything

if we add a `join` the program still exits.

how do we wait for all the workers to finish what they need to do in

`pool.apply_async` in `gevent`

Answer (score 1):

This works just fine for me.

```
import gevent
from gevent.monkey import patch_all
from gevent.pool import Pool

pool = Pool(10)

def print_num(num):
    print(num)


numbers  = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for number in numbers:
   pool.apply_async(print_num, args=(number,))

pool.join()
```

**Concurrency is not multi-threading**

When the pool.join is not called then the greenlets are never scheduled. When the join is called then the greenlets do not run as a separate thread.
[Concurrency versus parallelism.](http://learn-gevent-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/general_concepts.html#what-s-the-difference-between-concurrency-and-parallelism)